# How to you variable groups in azure biceps file

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-bicep

How to use variable groups in azure biceps file

In order to pass variables like retention days and others from library

I haven't tried yet

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of details for someone to be able to help you. I would suggest you read over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then improve your question so we can help you.

Comment: *I haven't tried yet*. This is your first problem. Please review documentation on the tools you're trying to use, formulate a solution, attempt to implement that solution, and ask a question here if you encounter some difficulty that you can't resolve on your own.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As one of ways.. if you use variable groups as DEV/TEST/PROD envs, you may build your bicep file with parameters by:

```
az bicep build --file {your_file}
```

Then use generated ARM template in [AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-v3?view=azure-pipelines) task and assign values from your variable groups through overrideParameters section:

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    subscriptionId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    resourceGroupName: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    location: 'XXXXXXXX'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/arm-template.json'
    overrideParameters: '-param1 "$(param_value1)" -param2 "$(param_value1)"'
```